# Amazon Web Services Elastic Beanstalk Pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed a simple webapp on AWS using the free tier. It's just a Tomcat instance running a webapp. I don't have all that much knowledge about AWS and Google hasn't helped either. I've read something about 750 hours of instance per month for 12 months, does this apply to my scenario or can I use the instance "forever"? Even if it does, would creating a new instance with a different webapp result in an automatic upgrade from the free tier? Is there something else I should know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) includes Amazon EC2:

- 750 hours per month of Linux, RHEL, or SLES t2.micro or t3.micro instance dependent on region
- 750 hours per month of Windows t2.micro or t3.micro instance dependent on region
- Valid for the first 12 months of your AWS Account

Therefore, if your application is running on a `t2.micro` or `t3.micro` Amazon EC2 instance, and that is the only EC2 instance running, then there will be no charge for the first 12 months of your AWS Account.

Think of the Free Tier as a billing discount where, each month, the first 750 hours of applicable usage is charged at a zero price. Any usage beyond those hours, or on other Instance Types, would be charged as normal.

Comment: So after 12 months I need to pay? And therefore I also have to pay as soon as I add another instance?

Comment: Yes, if you wish to run more than one instance continuously, then it will consume more than the 750 free hours available each month. And, yes, the free hours for Amazon EC2 are only for the first 12 months of your AWS Account, after which the 750 hours/month are no longer provided.